# Sign In With Apple not returning the same codes for web and mobile

Tags: javascript, html, swift, sign-in-with-apple

I am using SignInWithAppleJS for my website and Sign In With Apple for my swift App. But the userId tokens are not the same, nor are the auth codes. I need one similar variable returned from the request in order to know if the same user has signed in on both mobile and web. What am value is the same for both services?

Comment: The user's email address is supposed to be provided in all returns.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/useri/3530386-email

Comment: The auth codes change every 10 min I believe but the user should be the same per app

Comment: @TimRoberts email is nil after 1st authentication for me

Comment: @loremipsum user is different for me when I do it on iOS vs web...